# how to disable the default toolbar of pdf page

Tags: pdf

I need to provide some security of pdf page by disable the toolbar, no right click, no text selection, no cope-paste. Can anyone please tell me how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do it. To my knowledge there is now way to programatically disable the toolbars or any of the features you are describing. And it is certainly the wrong way of providing security to a document. Maybe you should look at alternative formats.

As a general rule of thumb, if someone can see it on their computer, they can duplicate it.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to disable the toolbar or right-click functionality in Adobe Reader (or any other reader) -- this is not a feature of the PDF specification . However, it is possible to disable content (text, images, etc) copying using a number of different PDF libraries. You can also prevent printing, page extraction, document modifications, etc.

Two PDF developer libraries that would offer you this functionality are:

- [Quick PDF Library](http://www.quickpdflibrary.com/)
- [Solid Framework](http://www.soliddocuments.com/products.htm?product=SolidFramework)