# How to remove scrollbars on WebBrowser in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, c#-4.0

I am using WebBrowser control in my application like:

```
<WebBrowser x:Name="wcPlayback" Visibility="Visible" LoadCompleted="wcPlayback_LoadComplete" Margin="0,-4,0,0" Width="960px" Height="619px" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"></WebBrowser>
```

I did many tries to remove scrollbar but failed.

Please help me.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930297/disable-wpf-webbrowser-scrollbar

Answer (score 9):

In case you can modify the web page you want to load, just modify the body tag as below:

```
<body scroll="no">
```

It worked for me.

Follow this link for more details: 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a64e2247-c726-473e-bed2-12a2b4454ede/how-to-show-hide-scrollbars-in-new-35-sp1-beta-wpf-webbrowser-control?forum=wpf

Comment: Or even better: `scroll="auto"`, the browser will then only show the scrollbar if needed.

Answer (score 8):

I used this code and worked for me:

```
<WebBrowser LoadCompleted="wb_LoadCompleted"></WebBrowser>           

void wb_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    string script = "document.body.style.overflow ='hidden'";
    WebBrowser wb = (WebBrowser)sender;
    wb.InvokeScript("execScript", new Object[] { script, "JavaScript" });
}
```

**[edit]**

The point is, you need to set `overflow: hidden;` in your page css. The code above is doing it.

Comment: Unknown InvokeScript function.

Comment: So, it looks like a bad reference for `WebBrowser` class. Check this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc452443.aspx

Comment: You can try to modify the code as they described in their MSDN reference's example;)

Comment: webbrowser control does not allowed me to hide its own scrollbar in wpf

Comment: I don't know, that code works for me. I have just checked it. No scrollbars at all:/

Answer (score 4):

In my case, script from [Nickon's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17087470/2707159) answer abow, does not work:

```cs
string script = "document.body.style.overflow ='hidden'" // Does not work;
```

but this works:

```cs
string script = "document.documentElement.style.overflow ='hidden'" //Work for me;
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this to change the body string directly:

```
wcPlayback.Document.Body.scroll = "no";
```