# Hide scrollbar in webbrowser

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to hide scroll bar with

```
ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
```

Here is my code:

```
<WebBrowser ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Name="web3D" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="340" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="500"/>
```

But it still visible, what am doing wrong?

Comment: is this silverlight or wpf?

Comment: This is WPF, I`ll fix the headline

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930297/disable-wpf-webbrowser-scrollbar

Comment: Another possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17086927/how-to-remove-scrollbars-on-webbrowser-in-wpf

Comment: The  WPF WebBrowser is only a wrapper around the Internet Explorer.  The scrollbar it displays is owned by the IE.