# How can I embed a PDF in a webpage without showing the Firefox PDF viewer toolbars?

Tags: html, firefox, pdf, web

How can I embed a PDF in a webpage without showing the Firefox PDF viewer toolbars (and the toolbar overlay in Chrome)?

Adding `#toolbar=0` doesn't seem to affect these viewers.

I don't want to protect the PDF, I want to make it look cleaner/better on the website.

## Current

[image]

## Desired

[image]

Comment: Have you solved this? This works well in chrome but not in FF.

Answer (score 4):

try it
CSS:

```
    div.pdf {
   position: absolute;
  top: -42px;
  left: 0;width:100%;
  }
```

and html is:

```
<div class="pdf"><embed src="http://URL_TO_PDF.com/pdf.pdf">
```

Comment: I think that you should apply css to the embed element itself, and use ```margin-bottom: -42px```

Comment: Nice solution with position absolute and negative values, works for me

Answer (score -1):

Adding `#toolbar=0` effects all the browsers except `Mozilla Firefox`, and there is no way to turn toolbar off or make it disable in `Mozilla Firefox` till today.

You can use it like this:

```
<embed
  src="http://URL_TO_PDF.com/pdf.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0"
  width="425" height="425" />
```

Answer (score -2):

This question was asked before in a different way.
You should try something like this in your src="" :

```
<embed src="http://URL_TO_PDF.com/pdf.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" width="425" height="425">
```

Here is the reference link:  [Hiding the toolbars surrounding an embedded pdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104608/hiding-the-toolbars-surrounding-an-embedded-pdf)

Key note:
This does not work in FireFox

Comment: This doesn't work for me, does it work for you in Firefox with the default PDF viewer (not Adobe)?

Comment: This question was asked a little differently in a security question.  I will update the answer.

Comment: You've copied the answer for a question about Adobe that has a reply saying it doesn't work in Firefox.