# Disable copy and print options in pdf viewer

Tags: html, css

I have used  tag to display documents (files). In that pdf files are displayed with print and download options i need to remove that print and download options in pdf viewer is there any way to hide it.

Below is my html code to view pdf document

```html
<iframe class="iframemargins" src="{{ url('uploads/chapters/Author.pdf') }}" 
        title="PDF in an i-Frame" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" width="100%" 
        height="600px">
</iframe>
```

Is there any other way to display files like pdf, doc, txt, rtf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution in this... here is the link where i got a solution

[Hiding the toolbars surrounding an embedded pdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104608/hiding-the-toolbars-surrounding-an-embedded-pdf)

And i have updated my html code as below and its working

```
<iframe src="{{ url('uploads/chapters/Author.pdf') }}#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" title="PDF in an i-Frame" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></iframe>
```

Comment: But toolbar=0 would also disable the bookmarks and page numbers functionality. Isn't it. What about disabling only the print and download buttons ?

Comment: Does that disable the context menu when you right click the document on the browser with allows to save the document or to open it on another application?

Answer (score 0):

Use [PDF.js](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/getting_started/) that has provided you source of PDF viewer. Simply remove these buttons from `web/viewer.html`.

Please note that your URL will have to change to `web/viewer.html?file={{ url('uploads/chapters/Author.pdf') }}` as specified [here](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#can-i-specify-a-different-pdf-in-the-default-viewer)

---

To view MS Office documents, use something like [Zoho](https://www.zoho.com/)

Comment: how to use pdf.js file i need documentation

Comment: @Vinothini Instead of linking directly to PDF itself, link iframe to your viewer.html page with `file` parameter

Comment: I have post my answer see below

Comment: @Vinothini For MS Office - Zoho Docs, for simple files - `file_get_contents` in PHP

Comment: how can i view a file in front end so that i must use html know?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the print media query to hide elements in print. see the example below.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("print");
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    window.print();
});
```

```css
@media print {
    .print {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<h3 style='text-align: center'>My Table</h3>
<table border='1' style='border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;'>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Heading 1</th>
    <th>Heading 2</th>
    <th>Heading 3</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
    <th>Value 1</th>
    <th>Value 2</th>
    <th>Value 3</th>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Value 1</th>
    <th>Value 2</th>
    <th>Value 3</th>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Value 1</th>
    <th>Value 2</th>
    <th>Value 3</th>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Value 1</th>
    <th>Value 2</th>
    <th>Value 3</th>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<button class='print'>Download</button>
<button class='print' id='print'>Print</button>
```

Comment: This is not what i want actually i need to display pdf file without print and download options using iframe tag

Comment: you mean to hide the download and print options of the browser print preview?

Comment: No, document viewer using iframe in html element