# How do I get rid of the sidebar and toolbar when embedding a pdf in an html file?

Tags: html, pdf

Trying to embed a pdf on my website like so:

```
<iframe src="filename.pdf" type='application/pdf' frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

The website is a rails site, and currently I'm only running it on a local server.

The problem is that the pdfs render with a toolbar on top and a sidebar with my adobe creative cloud account information, as seen in the picture below (the actual content of the pdf displays in the white box under the toolbar and to the left of the sidebar)

[image]

How can I get the pdf to render alone, without the menu and sidebar?

Answer (score 1):

If you allow the browser to choose how the PDF gets rendered, you're *never* going to be able to create a consistent experience for your users unless you are in a controlled desktop environment.

If you are looking for a consistent experience, use pdf.js to render the PDF in the browser.

If you *are* in a controlled environment and all of your users have a browser/viewer combination that will let the browser show PDF using the Adobe Reader plugin (as your screen shot shows) then you can use the "open parameters" at the end of the URL to control what gets shown. See the documentation at the link below.

http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf

That said, don't count on that solution to work for very long. Most modern browsers are not allowing the viewer plugins to function anymore and the rest are moving in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

Searching more into stack, try that:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2105095/7741129

For more detailed informations:

http://blogs.adobe.com/pdfdevjunkie/web_designers_guide

I think it's better use some kind of JS stuff just in case of cross-browser issues, like related into first link. Solutions like https://pdfobject.com/ it's helpful to get the job done. Look:

> PDFObject 2.0 detects browser support for inline/embedded PDFs. (In
>   case you were wondering, your browser supports embedded PDFs. You
>   lucky dog, you!)
>
> If you're working with dynamic HTML, such as a single-page web app,
>   you may need to insert PDFs on-the-fly. However, PDF embedding is not
>   supported by certain browsers. If you insert markup without first
>   checking for PDF support, you could wind up with missing content or a
>   broken UI.
>
> The PDFObject utility helps you avoid these situations by detecting
>   support for PDF embedding in the browser; if embedding is supported,
>   the PDF is embedded. If embedding is NOT supported by the browser, the
>   PDF will NOT be embedded.
>
> By default, PDFObject 2.0 inserts a fallback link to the PDF when the
>   browser does not support inline PDFs. This ensures your users always
>   have access to your PDF, and is designed to help you write less code.
>   The fallback link can be customized, or the option can be disabled if
>   you prefer.
>
> PDFObject 2.0 is npm-ready. Modern web apps use npm to manage packages
>   and dependencies. PDFObject 2.0 is registered with Node Package
>   Manager (npm) and can be loaded dynamically.
>
> PDFObject also makes it easy to specify Adobe's proprietary "PDF Open
>   Parameters". (Be warned these parameters are only supported by Adobe
>   Reader, most PDF readers will ignore the parameters, including the
>   built-in PDF readers in Chrome, Internet Explorer, and Safari. Read
>   more below.)

Comment: I wrote the Web Designer's Guide to Acrobat that's referenced above. Thanks for the link but I have to say it's horribly out of date.