# How to remove Download option from pdfkit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdfkit

I want to make a dynamic pdf online using my form on left side and pdf on right side in my react app.
But I want my own button to work as a download button rather than a download button in the pdfviewer.

I can disable print option by doing so:

```
const doc = new PDFDocument(
                options:{
                   permissions:{
                        printing:false
                    }
                });
```

but I am unable to find a similar option for disabling download option.
Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104608/hiding-the-toolbars-surrounding-an-embedded-pdf

Comment: It's for a existing pdf, I am creating pdf using pdfkit. which needs to be loaded by pdfkit itself.